# Need help to declare public function or method

Tags: c#

Hi? Anyone could help me how to rewrite the following function publicly so I could call it from another form or class

```
DataTable GetData(string connstr, string qrystr)
{
    var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@connstr);
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand comm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(qrystr, conn);
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    dtbl.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
    return dtbl;
}
```

Comment: It's pretty simple. You should read about [access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx).

Comment: By the way you are not closing your db connection. I am going to edit your question with the correct response rather than put it in the answers since that is not your question.

Comment: Also note that while you can make it public you can't make it global.

Answer (score 1):

For a method, **[`Private`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)** is the default if no access modifier is specified.
To make it Public

Just add **[`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx)**

```
public DataTable GetData(string connstr, string qrystr)
    {
        var conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@connstr);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand comm = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(qrystr, conn);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        dtbl.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());
        return dtbl;
    }
```